# Multiple displot (sns) in one figure - removing titles from individual plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am following the code given [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html) to embed multiple distplots in the same figure:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, hue = "sex", row="day",
              height=1.7, aspect=4,)
g.map(sns.distplot, "total_bill", hist=False)
```

that gives me

[image]

However, I would really like to get rid of the subtitles "day = ...".
I have tried multiple options and the best so far is

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, margin_title = True, hue = "sex", row="day",
              height=1.7, aspect=4,)
g.map(sns.distplot, "total_bill", hist=False)
```

This however, just moves the subtitle to the right:

[image]

Suggestions on how to get rid of the subtitles completely would be very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, hue = "sex", row="day",
              height=1.7, aspect=4,)
g.map(sns.distplot, "total_bill", hist=False)
for ax in g.axes.flat:
    ax.set_title('')
```